# Selenium send keys not working on instagram comments

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to automate comments under an ig post but it doesn't work.
it gives a generic send_keys error.
the script crashes after clicking the ig comment box.

class InstagramBot:

```
def autocomment(self):
    driver = self.driver
    comment_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh")
    comment_box.clear()
    time.sleep(2)
    comment_box.send_keys(self.comment)
    time.sleep(10)
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
username = "test"
password = "test"

ig = InstagramBot(username, password)
ig.login()
ig.nav_user()
while True:
    ig.autocomment()
```

error:  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})

Comment: What is the value of `self.comment`? Is the result the same with different values?

Comment: I tried different values but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you are already logged in and inside a post the code below should work fine.

```
def autocomment(self, profile_name, comment):
    driver = self.driver    
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + profile_name + "/")
    time.sleep(2)
    comment_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
    comment_box.click()
    comment_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
    comment_box.send_keys(comment)
    comment_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

ig.autocomment("profile_name", "blabla")
```

As far as your code concerned :

```
comment_box.send_keys(self.comment)
```

After commenting you should have had submitted it in some way.

Last but not least I don't think this line below is necessary as every-time the comment box
is empty by default.

```
comment_box.clear()
```

For any additional help please tell me as it's my first time answering a question.